# Subsection name in the header appearing from last section

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, subsection

I am using `article` class with `twoside` option to prepare a document. In the headers, I want the left page headers to contain the `section`, whereas the right page headers to contain the `subsection`. I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CE]{\Sectionname}
\fancyhead[CO]{\Subsectionname}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{Subsection 1.1}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \section{Section 2}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

This works well, until a section appears with no subsections. In that case, the right headers are continuing with the last subsection of the last section. I want those right page headers to go blank. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The shortest (and tricky) solution is to add, under each section without subsection, a subsection with empty title: \subsection{}. That works! But is not the better solution.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro, that does not serve the purpose at all!

Comment: (Not tested.)  Just after a `\section` that will have no subsections, try inserting `\subsectionmark{ }`.  But might not this same thing happen if you have a section beginning on the right-hand page, the last subsection was on the left-hand page, and the next subsection (in the new section) doesn't begin until the next (left0hand) page?  (An edge case, to be sure.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, Yes, as you anticipated, `\subsectionmark{}` works fine usually, but fails in the edge cases. Also the **and** in the edge case "...left-hand page, _and_ the next subsection..." you mentioned, should actually be an **OR**. Consider [this](https://pastebin.com/cR5R97jV) and [this](https://pastebin.com/7c36Efxa) MWE's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the next code solves your problem in every case:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EC]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OC]{\lastrightmark}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\lipsum[1-40]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1-23]
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\lipsum[24-45]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you so much.